# Parsing Json string for variable arguments function call in C language

Tags: c, json

In one of the module, Json string is received through socket. json string has array object named as "`args`".

The array can have any number of object even zero. Each object has type and value. type can have be `%s` or `%d`. value can have string or integer as indicated by type.

eg:

```
args: [ {type: "%d", value: 10}, {type:"%s", value: "abc"}, ...]
```

after receiving the json string , a variable argument function needs to called.
eg:

```
 cbptr_func("%d%s", 10, "abc");
```

Since number of each type specifier and their order is not fixed in a json string, Is there any way to pass the arguments to function in C language.

Cheers
Gnana

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no realistic way to accomplish this in the way described. You can't create a dynamic number of arguments to a function in C.

Instead you should probably pass the format string together with an array of int values and an array of string values. For your example you'd call the function like this:

```
cbptr_func("%d%s", (int[]){10}, (const char *[]){"abc"});
```

Then when you read %d from the format you read a value off the int array, and when you read %s you read a value off the string array.

If your goal is to use a printf function, then you will have to call it repeatedly once for each argument, concatenating the resulting string between the calls.